# Printing out prime numbers from an array given a max number

Tags: ruby, primes

Is there a shorter or maybe a cleaner way of doing:

> Using your `is_prime?` method, write a new method, `primes` that takes a (non-negative, integer) number `max` and returns an array of all prime numbers less than `max`.

```
def is_prime?(max)
  i = 2
  while i < max
    is_divisible = ((max % i) == 0)
    if is_divisible
      # divisor found; stop and return false!
      return false
    end

    i += 1
  end

  # no divisors found
  true
end
def primes(max)
  primes_arr = []

  i = 2
  while i < max
    if is_prime?(i)
      # i is prime; add it to the array
      primes_arr << i
    end

    i += 1
  end

  # return primes_arr
  primes_arr
end
```

Comment: Yes, there is an algorithm that works 300x faster than one you described, see full details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792960/why-doesnt-my-ruby-coding-for-finding-prime-numbers-work/32806718#32806718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same logic, a bit cleaner and more rubular:

```
def is_prime?(num)
  (2...num).each do |divisor|
    return false if num % divisor == 0
  end

  true
end

def primes(max)
  primes = []

  (2...max).each do |num|
    primes << num if is_prime?(num)
  end

  primes
end
```

Comment: Would you happen to know a similar way of printing out the primes up to (max) number without the without using "is_prime" method?

Comment: @ZeroOne something like this? <https://gist.github.com/micahbf/7299091>

Comment: https://gist.github.com/micahbf/7299091

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using [`Prime#prime?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime-3F):

> Suppose I want to get all the prime numbers less than `9`

```
require 'prime'

a = (1..12).to_a
p a.select{|e| e.prime? and e < 9 }
# >> [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Here is a method

```
require 'prime'

def prime_below_max(a,max)
   a.select{|e| e.prime? and e < max }
end

ary = (1..12).to_a
p prime_below_max(ary,9)
# >> [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: The OP is supposed to write the methods for one of the online Ruby quizzes, not take advantage of built-in classes. While this is shorter on the surface it skirts the issue of working with the OPs code to optimize it.

Comment: @theTinMan I thought OP asked us to provide a short and simple code...Now I got what was he looking for... Should I delete this?

Comment: `Prime.each(100).to_a` is even shorter

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote `is_prime?`. It's more robust (doesn't fail when `n < 2`) and has caching and basic tests.

```
require 'set'

# Returns true if a number is found to be prime and caches it for quick lookup.
# Uses the simple trial division method.
def is_prime?(n)
  @primes ||= Set.new  # Prefer set over array because of constant-time checks.
  return true if @primes.include?(n)
  return false if n < 2

  (2...n).each do |i|
    return false if n % i == 0
  end

  @primes.add(n)
  true
end

def run_tests
  tests = {
    -1 => false,
    0 => false,
    1 => false,
    2 => true,
    3 => true,
    4 => false,
    5 => true,
    9 => false,
    913 => false,
    997 => true,
    3571 => true,
  }

  tests.each do |num, is_prime|
    # Tests primality.
    if is_prime?(num) == is_prime
      print "PASS: "
    else
      print "FAIL: "
    end
    if is_prime then puts "#{num} is prime" else puts "#{num} is not prime" end

    # Tests caching of primes.
    if is_prime && @primes.include?(num)
      print "PASS: "
    elsif !is_prime && !@primes.include?(num)
      print "PASS: "
    else
      print "FAIL: "
    end
    if is_prime then puts "#{num} should be cached" else puts "#{num} should not be cached" end
    puts
  end
end

run_tests
```

If you need a better primality test (in Ruby) I recommend the `Prime` class, or if that's not possible for whatever reason, implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm.

Comment: You only cache the fact that certain numbers are prime, but not the fact that other numbers are non-prime. That guarantees a low cache hit rate.

Comment: @200_success that's a good point, thanks for bringing that up. The set can be changed to a hash. The tradeoff is that it would be faster at the expense of taking up more space (which is usually worth it).

Comment: Note that you can also speed up trial division by iterating up to `sqrt(n)`. E.g. `2.upto(Math.sqrt(n).to_i) do |i|`